# JS error only with opened Chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Today I faced with some black magic in Chrome 50.0.2661.102 m on Windows 10.

I was developing app (devtools was opened), all was fine. Suddenly, after page refresh I got JS error throwed from a place in my code, like smth is undefined.
I reverted sources to 100% working commit, but it was still present. I tried Opera and Edge it worked well. When I closed devtools in Chrome it "fixed" app and all was fine.
But when I opened devtools again it throwed the same error. I checked in Firefox and it prints the same stack trace. I tried to reboot pc and to rebuild a project. Nothing helped.

So, does anyone know what is going on?

P.S. More useful info:
I use CacheKiller, and tried incognito tab.
NodeJS server running with IntelliJ IDEA 15.
Project contain CommonJS modules which are build to a single bundle.js with browserify.

Added stack trace (I think it is absolutly not useful):

```
web-app.min.js:182 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
React.createClass._addGameBoxToScene
 @ web-app.min.js:182CoverFlow_componentWillReceiveProps
 @ web-app.min.js:233(anonymous function)
 @ web-app.min.js:331assign.notifyAll
 @ web-app.min.js:11396UPDATE_QUEUEING.close
 @ web-app.min.js:24319Mixin.closeAll
 @ web-app.min.js:26355Mixin.perform
 @ web-app.min.js:26302assign.perform
 @ web-app.min.js:24348flushBatchedUpdates
 @ web-app.min.js:24409ReactUpdates_flushBatchedUpdates
 @ web-app.min.js:22995NESTED_UPDATES.close
 @ web-app.min.js:24307Mixin.closeAll
 @ web-app.min.js:26355Mixin.perform
 @ web-app.min.js:26302assign.perform
 @ web-app.min.js:24348flushBatchedUpdates
 @ web-app.min.js:24409ReactUpdates_flushBatchedUpdates
 @ web-app.min.js:22995Mixin.closeAll
 @ web-app.min.js:26355Mixin.perform
 @ web-app.min.js:26302ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates
 @ web-app.min.js:19075enqueueUpdate
 @ web-app.min.js:24438enqueueUpdate
 @ web-app.min.js:24026ReactUpdateQueue.enqueueSetState
 @ web-app.min.js:24192ReactComponent.setState
 @ web-app.min.js:15798(anonymous function)
 @ web-app.min.js:459fire
 @ web-app.min.js:3935self.fireWith
 @ web-app.min.js:4065done
 @ web-app.min.js:9505(anonymous function)
 @ web-app.min.js:9871
```

Comment: Can you add some specific information about the error?

Comment: Your question isn't really helpful. According to the things you state in the question, everything should work.

Comment: How do you know you aren't getting an error when the dev tools are closed?

Comment: It sounds like some tiny race condition whose timing is perturbed by running in debug mode.

Comment: Because ReactJS components rendered and all works like should work. When error happens page is empty,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god, it was a very sly bug, I should stop coding at the night :-)

My code has a value, that I calculate depending on the screen proportions. And there were an error in a calculation formula. It returned not an integer value, and I use this value to acess the array element.

Problem occured only in few specific positions of devtools/browser splitter (which you drag to resize your work place). So when I tried other browsers it was ok because of different proportions. And previous commit worked untill I changed a devtools size...